# ListView with 2 tables

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, ado.net

Sample Output:

[image: 1]

1st column(ProductID) 2nd(ProductName) 3rd(OrderDate) and 4th column in Unpaid(Amount)
It is possible to have 2 tables in a ListView?

How to do this sample output, which gets the first table with a header(Orders) and display the total orders at the end of data and the second table with a header(Unpaid) and display the total amount at the end of the data using ListView?

Comment: In a word, no.  But if it's done in `Detail` view with no sorting (you'll likely have to inherit from ListView and build your own implementation for _real_ control), you can just construct rows to appear the way you like.  It's just text formatting.  Unless you're suggesting automated summaries and the like.  Any particular reason for ListView?

Comment: I dont know or any idea how i will do it, it just happened that i thought of ListView. Thank you :)